# How can I translate this sentence into predicates and quantifiers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

sentence : Every cube is larger than something else.

My Working:

P(x) = x is larger than something else

∀xP(x)

But the answer is something completely different. 
∀x (A(x) → B(x)) : the answer

How does the answer equal to this? And is there a trick to translating sentences into quantifiers and predicates that I don't know about Because this is just one of the questions I got wrong and for some reason I can't get any of these questions right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in your sentence you're missing the fact that x is a cube

So to stick with the solution notation i would go

$A(x)$="$x$ is a cube"

$B(x)$="$x>$something else"

Then the solution is indeed correct